# Spring Boot not picking up configuration from different application

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, cassandra

I have a two spring applications [DAO](https://github.com/samagra-comms/dao) and [Orchestrator](https://github.com/samagra-comms/orchestrator). Ideally, I would want to keep my Cassandra Config inside DAO and inject that config inside Orchestrator. Which is what I am trying to do. But it always tries to pick up the `spring.data.cassandra...` config from application.properties and ignores the one in [CassandraConfig](https://github.com/samagra-comms/dao/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uci/dao/config/CassandraConfig.java).

I have tried multiple combinations inside my [Application](https://github.com/samagra-comms/orchestrator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uci/orchestrator/Application/OrchestratorApplication.java) here but not able to figure this out. Even the [copied Cassandra config](https://github.com/samagra-comms/orchestrator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uci/orchestrator/Application/OrchestratorApplication.java) to Orchestrator seems to run and then spring tries to override it with Default configuration. The DAO works fine independently and the Orchestrator works fine if I provide Cassandra properties like `spring.data.cassandra...`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is picking up the default configuration for Cassandra as part of the [auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) process.

Please, try excluding [`CassandraDataAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.html) from Spring Boot's auto-configuration. Your code will look like:

```java
package com.uci.orchestrator.Application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@EnableKafka
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.uci.dao","com.uci.orchestrator", "messagerosa","com.uci.utils"})
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories("com.uci.dao")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.uci.dao.models", "com.uci.orchestrator"})
@PropertySource("application-messagerosa.properties")
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class })
public class OrchestratorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrchestratorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I think you can safely remove the line:

```java
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories("com.uci.dao")
```

as it is included in your dao `CassandraConfig` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.uci.dao")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {
  //...
}
```

Please, note that in addition I included `com.uci.dao` in your `ComponentScan` definition, it may be related with the problem as well:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.uci.dao","com.uci.orchestrator", "messagerosa","com.uci.utils"})
```

Comment: I was getting an `Attributes should be specified via @SpringBootApplication` so I added it over there - `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class })`. Still getting the same 
`required a bean named 'reactiveCassandraTemplate' that could not be found.` error where I either define is twice or not even once. :(

Comment: Hi @Chaks. Yes, of course, sorry, I updated the answer. In any way, I am afraid that I misunderstood your question then. If you are facing that error, probably the problem has to do with any dependency or misconfiguration. Please, can you provide the full error stack trace in your question? I think it could be of help.

Comment: Hi @Chaks. Were you able to try anything else? In your dependencies, I noticed you are using to different versions of Spring Boot dependencies, perhaps it can be of relevance. In addition, the DAO project has as dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive` whereas orchestrator defines `spring-data-cassandra`. Please, review that dependencies as well. Finally, please, as I told if would be great if you could include your error stack trace, at least the parts related to Cassandra, I think it would be helpful in the resolution of the problem

Comment: Please @Chaks, try including `com.uci.dao.config` in your `@ComponentScan` annotation: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.uci.orchestrator", "messagerosa","com.uci.utils", "com.uci.dao.config"})`: it may be the actual reason of your problem

Answer (score 0):

You must disable the autoconfiguration to read @EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.uci.dao"). You can do it:

Adding this property on application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration
```

or adding the *exclude* parameter on @SpringBootApplication in the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class)
```